# Wifi RTL8852AE not finding network, new install of ubuntu 22.04 over Windows 11

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

So, I guess that there's something wrong with the drivers, since after a research i saw that for some reason that Wireless Network adapter is not working in Ubuntu.

I followed this instructions [https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/] but didn't solve anything. I'm very lost, from what i read i have to blackl list a driver, but i don't know if i did it right. Please help, I'm a beginner, and I don't have much people around to ask, I'm doing my internship in cybersec but doing sysadmin tasks and have almost 0 help or advice.

```
$uname -r 
6.2.0-26-generic
```

```
$lsmod | grep rtw
rtw_8852ae             16384  0
rtw_8852a             696320  1 rtw_8852ae
rtw89pci               73728  1 rtw_8852ae
rtw89core             585728  2 rtw89pci,rtw_8852a
mac80211             1617920  2 rtw89pci,rtw89core
cfg80211             1241088  4 wl,rtw_8852a,rtw89core,mac80211
```

```
$lshw -C network
*-generic DESACTIVADO
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp2s0f0
       versión: ff
       serie: 38:d5:7a:37:5d:37
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 66MHz
       capacidades: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852ae driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:160 ioport:3000(size=256) memoria:54000000-540fffff
```

```
$nmcli device
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE          CONNECTION          
enp1s0    ethernet  conectado      Conexión cableada 1 
wlp2s0f0  wifi      no disponible  --                  
lo        loopback  sin gestión    --
```

```
$ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:69:93:56:4e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:d5:7a:37:5d:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
$lspci -k
0000:02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852ae
    Kernel modules: wl, rtw_8852ae
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I suggest that you remove the needless Broadcom driver: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Also, please edit your question to show the result of: `rfkill list all` and: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Terrance, thank you for taking time to reply to my post, i went into the bios and i made sure wifi was enabled, and i didnt find any physical switch on the computer nor keyboard. And i followed the link you sent me, but still is not working : (
This computer is Hp All in one 24cb1xxx

Comment: Hi @waltinator, thank you for your reply, i look at the network logs, but im not sure what do you want me to do, can you give a bit more explanation please, thank you!!

Comment: @chili555, hi! i do not have Broadcom driver, the driver is  rtw_8852ae

Comment: "i do not have Broadcom driver, the driver is rtw_8852ae" Please see your readings above: "Kernel modules: wl, rtw_8852ae" The module *wl* is a Broadcom driver. Confirm: `modinfo wl` Please remove it as I suggested.